# How can I save the high score in sprite kit using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

Im a complete beginner at programming. in the following code what i want to do is save the high score and i can't manage to do that. as you'll I'm using NSUserDefaults but it doesn't show in the screen once game is over. any help will be appreciated. i want the high score to show on the screen and it doesn't.

class WT: SKScene {

```
let showMessage = SKLabelNode()
let tryAgain = SKLabelNode()
var highScore = SKLabelNode()



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    showMessage.fontName = "Noteworthy-Light"
    showMessage.fontSize = 55
    showMessage.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
    showMessage.text = "Time's Up!"
    showMessage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.7)
    showMessage.name = "show Message"
    showMessage.hidden = false
    showMessage.zPosition = 100

    self.addChild(showMessage)

    tryAgain.fontName = "Noteworthy-Light"
    tryAgain.fontSize = 44
    tryAgain.fontColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    tryAgain.text = "Try Again!"
    tryAgain.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2 - 200)
    tryAgain.name = "T.A"

    self.addChild(tryAgain)

    highScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Noteworthy-Light")
    highScore.text = "0"
    highScore.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    highScore.fontSize = 35
    highScore.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    highScore.name = "hs"


    addChild(highScore)

    var ActionOne = SKAction.scaleBy(0.9, duration: 0.3)

    var ActionSequence = SKAction.sequence([ActionOne, ActionOne.reversedAction(), ActionOne, ActionOne.reversedAction()])

    tryAgain.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(ActionSequence))


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "T.A"){

        let myScene = Game(size: self.size)
        myScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
        self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)

    }

}

func saveHighscore(highScore:Int){


    if let currentHighscore:Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("highScore") as? Int{

        if(highScore > currentHighscore){

            NSUserDefaults.setValue(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        }
    }else{

        NSUserDefaults.setValue(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You might want to synchronize your settings after changing them so you write the modifications to the disk.
[Synchronize Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize)

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```